# nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting error after geting response from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm developing a server in Node JS where there are two routes - **Login and Signup**.

Whenever I do signup, I am getting response as success and the data is being stored in MongoDB database successfully and then I'm getting **[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...** in my console.

Note:- "The problem is in signup only not in login".

**postSignup() will be called when a user requests for signup which is validated according to schema and inserted in database.
I'm providing the code related to signup.**

**signup.js**

```
const { User } = require("../../models");
const createError = require("http-errors");

const postSignup = (req, res, next) => {
  //validation
  const validation = User.validate(req.body);

  if (validation.error) {
    const error = new Error(validation.error.message);
    error.statusCode = 400;
    return next(error);
  }

  //check Existence

  const user = new User(req.body);
  user
    .checkExistence()
    .then((result) => {
      if (result.check) {
        const error = new Error(result.message);
        error.statusCode = 409;
        return next(error);
      }

      user.save((err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return next(createError(500));
        }

      res.status(201).json({
          message: "User has been Successfully Created",
        });
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      next(createError(500));
    });
};

module.exports = {
  postSignup,
};
```

**User.js**

```
const { dbCon } = require("../configuration");
const { userValidator, logSchema } = require("../validator");
const { hashSync, compareSync } = require("bcryptjs");

class User {
  constructor(userData) {
    this.userData = { ...userData };
  }

  save(cb) {
    dbCon("users", (db) => {
      try {
        const hashPass = hashSync(this.userData["password"], 12);
        this.userData["password"] = hashPass;
        db.insertOne(this.userData);
        cb();
      } catch (err) {
        cb(err);
      }
    });
  }

  checkExistence() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      dbCon("users", async (db) => {
        try {
          const user = await db.findOne({
            $or: [
              { username: this.userData["username"] },
              { email: this.userData["email"] },
            ],
          });

          if (!user) {
            resolve({
              check: false,
            });
          } else if (this.userData["username"] === user.username) {
            resolve({
              check: true,
              message: "username already exists",
            });
          } else if (this.userData["email"] === user.email) {
            resolve({
              check: true,
              message: "email already exists",
            });
          }
        } catch (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
      });
    });
  }
  static validate(userData) {
    //console.log(userData);
    return userValidator.validate(userData);
  }

module.exports = User;
```

**userValidator.js**

```
const Joi = require("@hapi/joi");

const schema = Joi.object({
  username: Joi.string().alphanum().required().min(3).max(15),
  email: Joi.string().email().required(),
  password: Joi.string()
    .pattern(
      new RegExp(
        "^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$"
      )
    )
    .message(
      "Password must contain at least eight characters, at least one number and both lower and uppercase letters and special characters"
    )
    .required(),
  first_name: Joi.string().required(),
  last_name: Joi.string().required(),
});


module.exports = {
  schema
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue. I don't know what was the issue but I tried to change node version in mongo db connect and then used the new connect URL.

If it still doesn't work, then try to create new cluster and connect it again with new cluster.

Comment: Thanx buddy! Creating new cluster works! But i'm still confused what was the issue... 